# How do you build individual app inside Yocto Project Image?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

So, I'm toying with NXP's modular gateway and it seems to be working fine. However, the way I am doing things seems to be really inefficient, so, I'm begging for people's wisdom.

NXP's Modular IoT Gateway provides software that needs to be built with Yocto Project, using  bitbake. I found the portion of codes that I needed to temper and the recipes attached to it. But my problem is, everytime I need to build the source code, I have to build the whole SDCard Image that seems to have the entire Linux operating system attached to it. (I did use -minimal version of the image as the source build manual instructed). Naturally, it takes a lot of time to just build the image even if the change I'm making here is really tiny on the actual source code.

My question is this. Is there anyway that I can build the individual application with bitbake? My plan is to build only the recipes that are attached to the source codes I tempered and somehow build them and if they are resulted in something like, tar package, extract/copy them inside the Image that I already built. In summary,

1. Is that possible? (build and generate binaries of individual recipes)
2. How do you do that?

   I'm obviously new to the whole Yocto Project thing so, I tried my best to look for the answer but, it seems that I don't even know the right search keys for the question I'm asking.

   Thanks for reading my question and have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, even if it looks like it, only the modified recipes are being built. If you `bitbake` the image for a second time and just added a package, changed something in your recipe, whatever, then only the different things are being taken care of then the repackages into your image.

Exception: if you have set up your build with `INHERIT += "rm-work"`, because this throws everythingaway after the build then you obviously have to completely rebuild.

This, in turn, means that if a simple change to you application triggers a complete rebuild then you might be (involuntarily) doing something wrong.

For an option during the development process, have a look at `devtool`, especially its `add`, `modify` and `deploy-target` commands as pointed out [in the sdk manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.7.1/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#sdk-use-devtool-to-add-an-application). It can help in the workflow, but generally speaking you should always aim for correct recipes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. May I ask what 'set up one's build with INHERIT += "rm-work" ' means exactly? I did grep on the entire project directory and found myself quite a lot of them.But some of them seems to be the part where allows the entire build to use INHERIT += "rm-work" keyword. For instance, rm_work.bbclas or ref-classes.xml.

Exactly where do I have to look for it if I wanted to make sure that is not set with my build?

Comment: Added note: So, I looked into it more closely, now I am sure that there's no 'INHERIT += "rm-work"' enabled on my set-up.

I think just like you mentioned, it seems to be building the only modified part of the entire recipe collection. The  problem is, repackaging to make it as a single micro SD card image takes awful lot of time. I think I might have to my build VM to faster drive or something.

Comment: @PesozuSejin Unfortunately there's only one thing to say about doing Yocto/OpenEmbedded work in VMS: Don't do it. Its just too slow.

Comment: As it turns out, I can actually individually build the specific recipe and look for the binary so that I can move/copy that into the pre-built image. Now I'm in the middle of finding out how I would define where the binary will take place.

In my case, it's inside build directory's ./tmp/work/some kind  of machine name?/app name directory.

Anyway, thank you very much for helping me out. Have a great day!

Comment: @PesozuSejinno need to do it manually, you can use `devtool deploy-target`for this.